# how to toggle between diff and non diff editor?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I am using the @monaco-editor/react package in my React application and facing an issue with styling. Specifically, I need to apply absolute positioning to a section wrapper that seems to be part of the internal implementation of the @monaco-editor/react package's DiffEditor component. However, my CSS rules don't seem to be taking effect as expected.

I also don't want to unmount the component when toggling because I would be losing the edit history.

Is there a way to achieve this?

My approach is to have two editors that would be overlayed, however, when I use absolute, it ignores it since there is a section wrapper.

```
<div className={clsx(classes.TabContainer, view !== 'code' && classes.Hidden, classes.Relative)}>
                        <StyledButton
                            onClick={() => setShowDiff(!showDiff)}
                            active={view === 'asset'}
                            className={classes.DiffButton}
                        >
                            {showDiff ? 'Hide Diff' : 'Show Diff'}
                        </StyledButton>
                        <DiffEditor
                            className={clsx(classes.Editor, !showDiff && classes.Hidden)}
                            original={lastAppliedCode}
                            modified={project.code}
                            language="javascript"
                            theme="vs-dark"
                            options={{
                                minimap: { enabled: false },
                                renderSideBySide: false,
                                readOnly: false,
                                inDiffEditor: true,
                            }}
                            
                            onMount={handleDiffEditorDidMount}
                        />
                        <Editor
                            className={clsx(classes.Editor, showDiff && classes.Hidden)}
                            height={0}
                            language="javascript"
                            value={project.code}
                            onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
                            onChange={handleEditorChange}
                            theme="vs-dark"
                            options={{ minimap: { enabled: false }}}
                            wrapperProps={{
                                onKeyDown: (e) => {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                },
                            }}
                        />
```

SCSS:

```
.Editor {
    position:absolute !important; 
    border: 2px solid $dustyRose;
    border-radius: $roundedMd;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.DiffEditor {
    @extend .Editor; 
    position: absolute !important;
}
.Hidden {
    display: none;
}
```